# What base cases do I need in this strong induction proof?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

> [image]

If $n=10$, then $f(10)=3f\text{ floor(10/5)} + f\text { ceil(10/3)})=3f(2)+f(4)$

So I think I will need base cases $2,3,4$. Is this correct?

Comment: Not following.  $f$ is only defined on $\mathbb N$, there is no $f(3.3)$.  And just studying $n=10$ won't obviously be enough (at least, I don't see why it should be enough).

Comment: Sorry I forgot there are cielings there ... let me fix

Comment: @lulu I'm moving directory to the induction step because that tells us how many base cases we need in the first place

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "how many base cases" you need.  We already know the result for $\{2,\cdots, 9\}$.  Since $n≥10\implies \lfloor \frac n5\rfloor <n$ and $\lceil \frac n3\rceil<n$, assuming the claim for $n-1$ and below will suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a bit unclear as to the question, so I'll describe the induction.

We already know the claim for $n\in \{2,\cdots, 9\}$ (as it is given by the definition).

It is easy to verify the statement for $n\in \{10,11,12,13,14\}$ (by direct computation)

Assume that $n≥15$ and that we already know the claim up to $n-1$.  We remark that $\lfloor \frac n5 \rfloor$ and $\lceil \frac n3 \rceil$ are both $<n$ so we inductively we know that $$f\left(\lfloor \frac n5 \rfloor \right)≤\frac n5\quad\text {and}\quad f\left( \lceil \frac n3 \rceil\right)≤\frac n3+1$$

It follows that $$f(n)≤n\times \left(\frac 35+\frac 13\right)+1=\frac {14}{15}n+1$$

It is easy to verify that $$n≥15\implies \frac {14}{15}n+1≤n$$ so we are done.

Comment: The question is just asking what cases to prove in the base step

Comment: I think we have to prove all base cases where $n=2\dots 9$

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand what that means.  Rather, I don't understand how to separate that from the entire argument. If you read what I wrote, you'll see that my calculation requires that you handle $\{10,11,12,13,14\}$ separately.  Someone else might be able to tighten the estimates and do better.

Comment: the cases $\{2,\cdots, 9\}$ are all trivial.  the cases $\{10,11,12,13,14\}$ are easy but you have to write them out.

Answer (score 0):

No. In order to prove that the statement is valid when $n=10$, you'll only need to know that it is valid when $n=2$ and $n=4$.

Comment: But what about values like $n=20$ and such? Won't I need to prove more base cases now?

Comment: @KSplitX Since you wrote “base cases”, I assumed that what you had in mind was the first case in which there was something to prove (that is, when $n=10$).